# VCCWを使ってVagrantにWordPress環境を構築をしたいのですが、WP-CLIのところでエラーが出ます

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, virtualbox

お世話になります。

VCCWを使ってVagrantにWordPress環境を構築をしたいのですが、
WP-CLIをインストール（WP-CLIのレシピをインストール？）するところでエラーが出てしまいます。

エラーのところだけ抜粋すると、

```
==> vccw.dev: Thank you for installing Chef!
==> vccw.dev: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
==> vccw.dev: Detected Chef (latest) is already installed
==> vccw.dev: Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> vccw.dev: Running chef-solo...
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:42+00:00] INFO: Started chef-zero at chefzero://localhost:8889 with repository at /tmp/vagrant-chef/ea6a7db6f74a184edc4185c146c25738, /tmp/vagrant-chef/b7398e9c110fe852514cb03e9ef84ff5
==> vccw.dev:   One version per cookbook
==> vccw.dev:
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:42+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> vccw.dev: Starting Chef Client, version 12.14.89
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:42+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.14.89 ***
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:42+00:00] INFO: Platform: i686-linux
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:42+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 13790
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:51+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/vccw.dev
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:51+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[wpcli]", "recipe[wpcli::install]", "recipe[vccw]"] from CLI options
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:51+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[wpcli], recipe[wpcli::install], recipe[vccw]]
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:51+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [wpcli, wpcli::install, vccw]
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:51+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for vccw.dev
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:51+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:51+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:51+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found:
==> vccw.dev: resolving cookbooks for run list: ["wpcli", "wpcli::install", "vccw"]
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:55+00:00] ERROR: Could not read /tmp/vagrant-chef/b7398e9c110fe852514cb03e9ef84ff5/cookbooks/wpcli into a Chef object: Cookbook loaded at path(s) [/tmp/vagrant-chef/b7398e9c110fe852514cb03e9ef84ff5/cookbooks/wpcli] has invalid metadata: The `name' attribute is required in cookbook metadata
==> vccw.dev: [2016-09-24T16:01:55+00:00] ERROR: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/cookbook/cookbook_version_loader.rb:195:in `raise_metadata_error!'
==> vccw.dev: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/cookbook/cookbook_version_loader.rb:81:in `load'
==> vccw.dev: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/chef_fs/file_system/repository/chef_repository_file_system_cookbook_dir.rb:139:in `cookbook_version'
==> vccw.dev: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/chef_fs/file_system/repository/chef_repository_file_system_cookbook_dir.rb:84:in `chef_object'
==> vccw.dev: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/chef_fs/chef_fs_data_store.rb:314:in `block in get'
==> vccw.dev: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/chef_fs/chef_fs_data_store.rb:787:in `with_entry'
==> vccw.dev: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.14.89/lib/chef/chef_fs/chef_fs_data_store.rb:310:in `get'
==> vccw.dev: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-zero-5.1.0/lib/chef_zero/data_store/v1_to_v2_adapter.rb:47:in `block in get'
```

こんな感じでエラーが出ています。

ちなみにWP-CLIのインストールはできているようで、
ゲストOSで
    $ wp cli info
をたたくと

```
[vagrant@vccw ~]$ wp cli info
PHP binary:     /usr/bin/php
PHP version:    5.4.45
php.ini used:   /etc/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI global config:   /home/vagrant/.wp-cli/config.yml
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 0.21.1
```

と返します。

手詰まってしまいました。

いろいろ調べましたが、どう調べていいのかもよくわかっていません。

ご教示いただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いします

環境   
Windows10 Pro   
Virtual Box 5.1.4   
Vagrant 1.8.4   
ruby 2.3.1  
Chef Development Kit 0.17.17  
chef-client 12.13.37  
miya0001/vccw (virtualbox, 2.19.0)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ vagrant provision
```

を試してみてはいかがでしょうか。